# Why is the input to the lapply function in R not being created?

Tags: r, function, package, lapply

I am trying to use the R package found at: https://github.com/bluegreen-labs/phenor

It pulls data from the European phenological network (pep725) and climate data from https://surfobs.climate.copernicus.eu/dataaccess/access_eobs.php#datafiles and then applies processing to the data before fitting various phenological (timing of natural events in organisms like leaf unfolding) models.

I am very new to R (I usually use Matlab) and am having difficulties identifying the source of an error.

Some example code was provided with the package(found below the screenshot below). I should say,that this code is not pulling down the eobs data as expected (I have just downloaded it manually). Also, the pep725 data also has thrown up a funny quirk in one instance where a letter in the name of a csv file was pulled down as superscript (highlighted in the screenshot below) (which also caused the code to error). I manually changed this letter too. These points may be relevant to the error, hence why I am including them.

[image]

```
# This script shows how you download
# and format data from various data sources
# some data is included in the phenor manuscript repository

# download and optimize data tmp_path = "~/phenor_files"

# create temporay directory for some of the data
# if it doesn't exist if(!dir.exists(tmp_path)){   dir.create(tmp_path) }

# load or download necessary data
# [create a proper pep725login.txt file first] CHANGE: I changed the download function below pr_dl_pep725(credentials = "~/phenor_files/pep725login.txt",
                species = "Fagus",
                internal = FALSE,
                path = tmp_path)

# download eobs data, please register before using this function
# [might take a while]
#CHANGE: I changed the url here server_path = "https://surfobs.climate.copernicus.eu/dataaccess/access_eobs.php"
#CHANGE: I altered the filenames below products = c(   "tg_ens_mean_0.25deg_reg_v20.0e.nc",   "tn_ens_mean_0.25deg_reg_v20.0e.nc",   "tx_ens_mean_0.25deg_reg_v20.0e.nc",   "rr_ens_mean_0.25deg_reg_v20.0e.nc",   "elev_ens_0.25deg_reg_v20.0e.nc" )

lapply(products, function(product){   httr::GET(sprintf("%s/%s",server_path, product),
            httr::write_disk(sprintf("%s/%s",
                                     tmp_path,
                                     product),
                             overwrite = TRUE),
            httr::progress()) })


# format pep725 data (Fagus sylvatica) and save pep725_data = pr_fm_pep725(pep_path = tmp_path,
                            eobs_path = tmp_path) saveRDS(pep725_data,"~/phenor_files/pep725_demo_data.rds")
```

My problem is occurring in the last 4 lines above. When I run the code I am getting the error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : No E-OBS files found in the referred path !
> saveRDS(pep725_data,"~/phenor_files/pep725_demo_data.rds")
Error in saveRDS(pep725_data, "~/phenor_files/pep725_demo_data.rds") : 
  object 'pep725_data' not found
```

The error is coming from the function (pr_fm_pep725). I opened this function to view the source code and have identified the lines where the error is coming from as:

```
  eobs_data <- lapply(c("tg", "rr", "elev", 
                        "tn", "tx"), function(x) {
                          filename <- list.files(eobs_path,
                          sprintf("%s_ens_mean_%sdeg_reg[^/]*\\.nc",x, resolution)) 
                          if (length(filename) > 0) {
                            r <- raster::brick(sprintf("%s/%s", eobs_path, 
                                                       filename))
                            return(r)
                          }
                          else {
                            stop("No E-OBS files found in the referred path !")
                          }
                        })
```

I have looked at what `lapply()` does, so I know it applies a function to each element in the list/input. In this case, I am interpreting the input as a five strings, that respectively identify the five eobs files in the temporary folder, but the reason it's erroring out is because these strings are not being created correctly (and as a result, not being found in the folder). Is that correct?

If I am correct in my appraisal of what is going on, I have two questions:

1. why is the string not being created correctly? What does the [^/]*\ do in:

```
sprintf("%s_ens_mean_%sdeg_reg[^/]*\\.nc",x, resolution))
```

2. Why is "function" explicitly being included in the command below? My understanding of `lapply()` is that a function is the second input, but that the function is predefined. I don't see 'function' defined anywhere. Or is this a generic way of using the term?

The error comes from

```
  eobs_data <- lapply(c("tg", "rr", "elev", 
                        "tn", "tx"), function(x) {
                          filename <- list.files(eobs_path, sprintf("%s_ens_mean_%sdeg_reg[^/]*\\.nc", 
                                                                    x, resolution))
```

This is a screenshot of the files I have in the 'phenor_files' directory:
[image]

This is the source code for the function ('pr_fm_pep725'):

```
function (pep_path = tempdir(), eobs_path = tempdir(), bbch = "11", 
          species = NULL, offset = 264, count = 60, resolution = 0.25, 
          pep_data) 
{
  format_data <- function(site = site, offset = offset) {
    pep_subset <- pep_data[which(pep_data$pep_id == site), 
    ]
    points <- sp::SpatialPoints(cbind(pep_subset$lon[1], 
                                      pep_subset$lat[1]), proj4string = sp::CRS(raster::projection(eobs_data[[1]])))
    tmean <- raster::extract(eobs_data[[1]], points)
    tmin <- raster::extract(eobs_data[[4]], points)
    tmax <- raster::extract(eobs_data[[5]], points)
    if (all(is.na(tmean))) {
      return(NULL)
    }
    else {
      precipitation <- raster::extract(eobs_data[[2]], 
                                       points)
      tmean <- matrix(rep(tmean, nrow(pep_subset)), length(tmean), 
                      nrow(pep_subset))
      tmin <- matrix(rep(tmin, nrow(pep_subset)), length(tmean), 
                     nrow(pep_subset))
      tmax <- matrix(rep(tmax, nrow(pep_subset)), length(tmean), 
                     nrow(pep_subset))
      precipitation <- matrix(rep(precipitation, nrow(pep_subset)), 
                              length(precipitation), nrow(pep_subset))
    }
    ltm <- as.vector(unlist(by(tmean[which(years >= 1980), 
                                     1], INDICES = yday[which(years >= 1980)], mean, na.rm = TRUE)))[1:365]
    lapse_rate <- as.vector((raster::extract(eobs_data[[3]], 
                                             points[1]) - pep_subset$alt[1]) * 0.005)
    tmean <- rbind(tmean + lapse_rate, pep_subset$year)
    tmin <- rbind(tmin + lapse_rate, pep_subset$year)
    tmax <- rbind(tmax + lapse_rate, pep_subset$year)
    ltm <- ltm + lapse_rate
    Ti <- apply(tmean, 2, function(x) {
      layers <- which((years == (x[length(x)] - 1) & yday >= 
                         offset) | (years == x[length(x)] & yday < offset))[1:365]
      return(x[layers])
    })
    Tmini <- apply(tmin, 2, function(x) {
      layers <- which((years == (x[length(x)] - 1) & yday >= 
                         offset) | (years == x[length(x)] & yday < offset))[1:365]
      return(x[layers])
    })
    Tmaxi <- apply(tmax, 2, function(x) {
      layers <- which((years == (x[length(x)] - 1) & yday >= 
                         offset) | (years == x[length(x)] & yday < offset))[1:365]
      return(x[layers])
    })
    Pi <- apply(rbind(precipitation, pep_subset$year), 2, 
                function(x) {
                  layers <- which((years == (x[length(x)] - 1) & 
                                     yday >= offset) | (years == x[length(x)] & 
                                                          yday < offset))[1:365]
                  return(x[layers])
                })
    if (offset < 365) {
      doy_neg <- c((offset - 366):-1, 1:(offset - 1))
      doy <- c(offset:365, 1:(offset - 1))
    }
    else {
      doy <- doy_neg <- 1:365
    }
    l <- ncol(Ti)
    Li <- daylength(doy = doy, latitude = pep_subset$lat[1])
    Li <- matrix(rep(Li, l), length(Li), l)
    data <- list(site = site, location = c(pep_subset$lat[1], 
                                           pep_subset$lon[1]), doy = doy_neg, ltm = ltm, transition_dates = pep_subset$day, 
                 year = pep_subset$year, Ti = Ti, Tmini = Tmini, Tmaxi = Tmaxi, 
                 Li = Li, Pi = Pi, VPDi = NULL, georeferencing = NULL)
    return(data)
  }
  message("* Merging and cleaning PEP725 data files in: \n")
  message(sprintf("  %s\n", pep_path))
  if (missing(pep_data)) {
    pep_data <- pr_merge_pep725(path = pep_path)
  }
  message(" |_ removing data out of range of the E-OBS climate data \n")
  pep_data <- pep_data[which(pep_data$year >= 1950 & pep_data$year <= 
                               max(pep_data$year)), ]
  if (is.null(species)) {
    message(" |_ including all species \n")
  }
  else {
    message(sprintf(" |_ selecting species: %s \n", 
                    species))
    pep_data <- pep_data[which(pep_data$species == species), 
    ]
  }
  message(sprintf(" |_ selecting phenophase: %s \n", 
                  bbch))
  pep_data <- pep_data[which(pep_data$bbch == bbch), ]
  message(sprintf(" |_ excluding sites with: < %s site years of observations \n", 
                  count))
  sites <- unique(pep_data$pep_id)
  counts <- unlist(lapply(sites, function(x) {
    length(which(pep_data$pep_id == x))
  }))
  selection <- sites[which(counts >= count)]
  pep_data <- pep_data[pep_data$pep_id %in% selection, ]
  if (nrow(pep_data) == 0) {
    stop("no data remaining after screening for the requested criteria\n         check your species name and observation count restrictions!")
  }
  sites <- unique(pep_data$pep_id)
  years <- unique(pep_data$year)
  message(sprintf("* Extracting E-OBS climatology for %s sites\n ", 
                  length(sites)))
  eobs_data <- lapply(c("tg", "rr", "elev", 
                        "tn", "tx"), function(x) {
                          filename <- list.files(eobs_path, sprintf("%s_ens_mean_%sdeg_reg[^/]*\\.nc", 
                                                                    x, resolution))
                          if (length(filename) > 0) {
                            r <- raster::brick(sprintf("%s/%s", eobs_path, 
                                                       filename))
                            return(r)
                          }
                          else {
                            stop("No E-OBS files found in the referred path !")
                          }
                        })
  yday <- as.numeric(format(as.Date(eobs_data[[1]]@z$Date), 
                            "%j"))
  years <- as.numeric(format(as.Date(eobs_data[[1]]@z$Date), 
                             "%Y"))
  pb <- utils::txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = length(sites), 
                              style = 3)
  env <- environment()
  i <- 0
  validation_data <- lapply(sites, function(x) {
    utils::setTxtProgressBar(pb, i + 1)
    assign("i", i + 1, envir = env)
    format_data(site = x, offset = offset)
  })
  close(pb)
  names(validation_data) <- sites
  class(validation_data) <- "phenor_time_series_data"
  validation_data <- validation_data[!unlist(lapply(validation_data, 
                                                    is.null))]
  return(validation_data)
}
```

Comment: 1) It's `list.files` argument `pattern`. It stands for any character but the bar `/`. `[^/]*` denotes the character class (`[]`) of characters *not* (first char in the class is the negation `^`) matching `/`.

Comment: 2) The function is defined as `function(x) {etc}`. It's an anonymous function. See Hadley Wickham's Advanced R [Functional Programming](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/fp.html).

Comment: @RuiBarradas Ok. I just read up on anonymous functions. In this case then, my 'x' is 'tg','tg'...etc and the anonymous function is making a filename?

Comment: @RuiBarradas: I have added a screenshot of the files that I have in the phenor_files directory. Can you see from the filenames why the code would not be creating the correct filename? I'm reading up of list.files now. Thank you.

Comment: Not quite, the function uses `filename <- list.files(.)` to get a filename in `path = eobs_path` matching the `pattern = sprintf(.)`. Then yes, the function's `x` will become each of `c("tg", "rr", "elev", "tn", "tx")` because that part of the code will `lapply` the `function(x)` to each of the that vector's elements. As for `resolution`, it seems to be `0.25`, right?

Comment: @RuiBarradas: Ok. I follow what you're saying. I think the problem here is that `x` is not being assigned the `c("tg", "rr", "elev", "tn", "tx")`. I can see that 'filename' remains empty, which means that the `length(filename)=0`, causing the error `No E-OBS files found in the referred path' to be returned.`

Comment: `x` *is* being assigned the right values, try assigning the return value of `sprintf` and print it before `list.files` to see what is the pattern and to see if there are matches in the working directory. Also, check the latter with `getwd()`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I'm not getting a return value for the `sprintf'`. The file name is not created yet for this to be returned. But also, the `eobs_path` appears to be wrong. At the start of the function it is being assigned the a path to a temporary directory `function (pep_path = tempdir(), eobs_path = tempdir(), bbch = "11", 
          species = NULL, offset = 264, count = 60, resolution = 0.25, 
          pep_data) `

Comment: @RuiBarradas If I define x using `c("tg", "rr", "elev","tn", "tx")` and define 'resolution' as 0.25, when I input `sprintf("%s_ens_mean_%sdeg_reg[^/]*\\.nc",x, 0.25)' I get back: '[1] "tg_ens_mean_0.25deg_reg[^/]*\\.nc"   "rr_ens_mean_0.25deg_reg[^/]*\\.nc"  
[3] "elev_ens_mean_0.25deg_reg[^/]*\\.nc" "tn_ens_mean_0.25deg_reg[^/]*\\.nc"  
[5] "tx_ens_mean_0.25deg_reg[^/]*\\.nc" `. Then when I try and expand the code further with `filename<-list.files(eobs_path,sprintf("%s_ens_mean_%sdeg_reg[^/]*\\.nc",x, 0.25))`, 'filename' is returned as: `"tg_ens_mean_0.25deg_reg_v20.0e.nc"`.